# Free / Open Source 2D Drafting CAD for Floor Plans

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source

I've been using PTC Creo for most of my design work in the past, but I'm trying to create a floor plan, and Creo Layout isn't designed for things like walls and doors or has support for standardized design sheet labels (at least it doesn't have a template or anything).  I'm looking for a free program that is 2D and will let me sketch out floor plans with thickness and doors as well as an info box in the bottom right that's properly formatted.  I need something that will let me make a building, not an engine block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [librecad](https://librecad.org/):

- Free (Gratis & OSS)
- Cross Platform
- Internationalisation to 20+ languges
- Lua scripting
- Active user community

[image: Example]
[image: Basement]

Answer (score 3):

### Offline & open source

- [Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/) (**my recommendation**).
- [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Dia?action=show&redirect=Dia)

### Web apps

Before you start using one, make sure it exports to a format you use, and at the "right" price.

- [Room Sketcher](http://planner.roomsketcher.com/#/?pid=493174)
- [Floor Planner](http://www.floorplanner.com/)
- [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com/users/registerLevel)

### Mobile apps

Plenty [in the the play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=floor%20plan&c=apps).

### Indices

- http://alternativeto.net/software/floorplanner/
- http://open-tube.com/ten-free-software-to-help-you-design-your-home/

Comment: If you are planning to use SweetHome 3D, you should also get the Advanced Editing plugin (available on the forum). It is pretty much a necessity to draw anything slightly more complex (odd angles, walls of different thickness)—unless you just want a visual impression that diesn’t need to be exactly to scale.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page as I had a similar question; [SketchUp Make 2017](https://www.sketchup.com/download/all) (which is the free version, as contrasted with SketchUp Pro) turned out perfect for my needs.  Gratis but not libre.

Not exactly self-explanatory, but I got a floor plan done okay by following [a blog post explaining exactly that](https://mastersketchup.com/sketchup-tutorial-how-to-create-a-quick-floor-plan/).

The key steps:

> 1. Start the line tool action by clicking once.
> 2. Drag the mouse toward the general direction you want to go.
> 3. Type in the length of the wall like this `18' 5"` and press `ENTER`.

I then found [this official tutorial video playlist](https://www.sketchup.com/learn/videos/826?playlist=58) for more in depth learning.